# nginx proxy_pass with dynamic upstream servers

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, internal-dns, proxypass, apache-mesos

We're currently stuck in a situation where we are using `nginx` as our main frontend server for a set of services backed by a dynamic DNS based service discovery with Mesos-DNS.

Our nginx configuration looks a bit like this;

```
http {
  resolver 10.10.1.1 valid=1s; // some internal DNS server
}

server {
  set $core_api core-api-service.marathon.mesos; // some internal DNS
  location /api {
    proxy_pass $core_api:8080; // resolve core_api DNS dynamically to one of the IP's of the slave the process is running + listening on
  }
}
```

Now the issue is that this setup works correctly, but one out of 4-5 requests always results in Nginx throwing back a 404, which makes no sense because none of the services running inside the cluster have moved to a different slave.

Now, the resolver `valid=1s` is quite aggressive, so we extended it to longer periods, thinking that maybe that was querying the DNS too often. But any value there causes the same problems. Removing the `valid=xx` also doesn't help.

What's going on here? How do we mitigate this?

Thanks.

**EDIT (full config)**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  .myapp.com;
    return       301 https://www.myappname.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen   80;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length  1100;
        gzip_buffers  4 32k;
        gzip_types    text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css;
        gzip_vary on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        server_name api.myappname.com;
        error_page 404 /static/404.html;
        error_page 403 /static/404.html;
        error_page 503 /static/503.html;
        error_page 502 /static/502.html;
        set $core_api http://core_api.marathon.mesos;

        location /api {
                if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
                        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
                }
                limit_req   zone=one  burst=35;
                limit_req_status 503;
                proxy_pass            $core_api:8080;
                proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

Comment: And what's in access and error logs? How do you know it's not your backend sends 404?

Comment: @AlexeyTen the nginx error log shows: 
`2015/10/05 13:26:13 [error] 523#523: *521888 core-api.marathon.mesos could not be resolved (3: Host not found), client: 10.0.7.21, server: ..., request: "PUT /api/v1/place/descriptive-parts HTTP/1.1", host: "www.myappname.com", referrer: "https://www.myappname.com/"
...`

Comment: That would be error 502, not 404. Anyway, first fix resolver