# Using Nginx upstream hosts with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Below is the bare-bones stripped down Nginx config that demonstrates the problem I'm having directly. The "real-world" setup has multiple upstreams and multiple conditional checks that are omitted for clarity.

```
upstream barhost {
  server example.com;
}

server {
  listen 8080;

  location / {

    # this works fine if used directly:
    # proxy_pass http://example.com/;

    # this doesn't work, returns 404:
    proxy_pass http://barhost/;
  }
}
```

**Results:**

- Using `proxy_pass http://example.com/;` works perfectly fine, returns **200**
- Using `proxy_pass http://barhost/;` (using `upstream`) it returns **404**

**Some background info:**

- The whole point of this dynamic upstream is to act as an alternative workaround for [this bountied and unsolved issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/1121736/nginx-is-not-handling-auth-request-before-if-statement).
- I cannot use `if()` to accomplish this particular goal, as explained in [a response to that related question](https://serverfault.com/a/1121907/583269), which is why I am going down this route (The idea is to use a `map` to decide on an `upstream`)
- It appears I cannot use `map` with the hostnames in it because [Nginx will not resolve DNS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71079945/13384507) if in a `map`, that's why I'm using `upstream`. I'm essentially [trying to mimic this config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50122194/13384507).

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Somewhat related posts:

- [nginx proxy_pass with dynamic upstream servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/726765/nginx-proxy-pass-with-dynamic-upstream-servers)
- [nginx dynamic proxy_pass with variable between redirections](https://serverfault.com/questions/893947/nginx-dynamic-proxy-pass-with-variable-between-redirections)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121492/using-nginx-map-directive-to-dynamically-set-proxy-upstream

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to a helpful user in the comments, I've investigated the request header that is proxied to example.com in this scenario. It's being set to `barhost` which the server will give an invalid response to. This is the root cause of the issue.

So, with that known, I would like to set the `Host` header properly.

Setting the upstream name to match the desired `Host` header name does work:

```
upstream example.com {
  server example.com:80;
}
```

Hard coding `Host` header with `proxy_set_header` also seems to work:

```
upstream barhost {
  server example.com;
}

server {
  listen 8080;

  location / {

    # This works:
    proxy_set_header Host example.com;

    # None of these work:
    # proxy_set_header Host $host;
    # proxy_set_header Host $http_upstream_host;
    # proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;

    proxy_pass http://barhost/;
  }
}
```

However, in my particular use-case it would ideal to instead set it dynamically using `proxy_set_header` using a variable - **is that possible?**

Comment: Have you looked at the request that's being made to the upstream server to figure out why you're getting a 404? Is it request the correct path? Is the `Host:` header correct?

Comment: @larsks You hit the nail on the head, thanks! So it's setting `Host` to `barhost`, I would like to overwrite this dynamically with `proxy_set_header`, do you know how to do this dynamically? I've put more details and findings in the original question. If not, feel free to respond about the Host header in the form of an answer and I'll gladly accept it since you've technically answered the question. I've added some working snippets above and would appreciate your insight on my follow up `proxy_set_header` question. Thanks again.